# I can't set visibilities of all TextView

Tags: android, textview

I want to assign values to TextView(birr) and make all them invisible.

But first TextView can't be set as invisible
I can't assign value to last TextView(ondort3)  when I make them visible.

There is problem with last and first one when I use loop 
How can I solve it?

```
int[] ids = new int[]{
                R.id.birr,R.id.iki,R.id.uc,R.id.dort,R.id.bes,R.id.alti,R.id.yedi,R.id.sekiz,R.id.dokuz,R.id.on,R.id.onbir,R.id.oniki,R.id.onuc,R.id.ondort,R.id.bir2,R.id.iki2,R.id.uc2,R.id.dort2,R.id.bes2,R.id.alti2,R.id.yedi2,R.id.sekiz2,R.id.dokuz2,R.id.on2,R.id.onbir2,R.id.oniki2,R.id.onuc2,R.id.ondort2,R.id.bir3,R.id.iki3,R.id.uc3,R.id.dort3,R.id.bes3,R.id.alti3,R.id.yedi3,R.id.sekiz3,R.id.dokuz3,R.id.on3,R.id.onbir3,R.id.oniki3,R.id.onuc3,R.id.ondort2,  };

  for(int id : ids){
     TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(id);
     t.setText("U");       
     t.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
```

layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

    tools:context="com.example.tarayici.MainActivity" >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kelime"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:columnCount="20"
        android:rowCount="10" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/birr"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="0"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/iki"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="2"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/uc"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="3"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />


     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dort"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="4"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

       <TextView
      android:id="@+id/bes"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="5"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
      android:id="@+id/alti"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="6"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

         <TextView
      android:id="@+id/yedi"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="7"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

          <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sekiz"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="8"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

           <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dokuz"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="9"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
      android:id="@+id/on"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="10"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

             <TextView
      android:id="@+id/onbir"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="11"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

              <TextView
      android:id="@+id/oniki"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="12"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

               <TextView
      android:id="@+id/onuc"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="13"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/ondort"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="14"
      android:layout_row="0"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />






    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/bir2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
       android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="0"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/iki2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="2"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/uc2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="3"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />


     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dort2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="4"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

       <TextView
      android:id="@+id/bes2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="5"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
      android:id="@+id/alti2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="6"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

         <TextView
      android:id="@+id/yedi2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="7"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

          <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sekiz2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_column="8"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

           <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dokuz2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="9"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
      android:id="@+id/on2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="10"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

             <TextView
      android:id="@+id/onbir2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="11"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

              <TextView
      android:id="@+id/oniki2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="12"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

               <TextView
      android:id="@+id/onuc2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="13"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/ondort2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="14"
      android:layout_row="1"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/bir3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
       android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="0"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/iki3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="2"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/uc3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="3"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />


     <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dort3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="4"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

       <TextView
      android:id="@+id/bes3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="5"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
      android:id="@+id/alti3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_column="6"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

         <TextView
      android:id="@+id/yedi3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="7"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

          <TextView
      android:id="@+id/sekiz3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="8"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

           <TextView
      android:id="@+id/dokuz3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="9"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
      android:id="@+id/on3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="10"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

             <TextView
      android:id="@+id/onbir3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="11"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

              <TextView
      android:id="@+id/oniki3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="12"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

               <TextView
      android:id="@+id/onuc3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
      android:layout_column="13"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/ondort3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="1sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="4sp"
      android:layout_column="14"
      android:layout_row="2"
      android:background="@layout/mybutton"
      android:paddingLeft="4dp"
      android:paddingRight="4dp"
      android:text="A"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />




            </GridLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:text="Go" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `But first TextView can't be set as invisible I can't assign value to last TextView(ondort3) when I make them visible.` **Unclear**. `There is problem with last and first one when I use loop` **Which** problem?

Comment: First TextView can't be set as invisible. When I try to assign value, last one can't be assigned

Comment: Check your id's, maybe you're using a wrong ones for the first and last TextViews.

Comment: Please check your English, too. I still can't understand the meaning of what you say.

Comment: I cheked xml files. All ids are unique.

Comment: Post the xml (layout) file

Comment: you have a `,` at the end of the array..see `R.id.ondort2,  `

Comment: @FrankN.Stein   I want to hide all TexView in Loop or assign a value. First TextView remains visible

Answer (score 1):

The last `TextView` id is missing in your array "**ondort3**".

```
int[] ids = new int[]{R.id.birr,R.id.iki,R.id.uc,...., R.id.ondort2,R.id.ondort3 };
```

Answer (score 0):

As, I mentioned in my comments, **you have a stray `,` in your array. Remove that**.

Replace

```
int[] ids = new int[]{...R.id.oniki3,R.id.onuc3,R.id.ondort2,  };
```

with

```
int[] ids = new int[]{...R.id.oniki3,R.id.onuc3,R.id.ondort2 };
```

**UPDATE**

**You are missing `id` of last `TextView` in your array.**

add `R.id.ondort3` to your array.That is, your array should be like,

```
int[] ids = new int[]{...R.id.oniki3,R.id.onuc3,R.id.ondort2,R.id.ondort3 };
```

Comment: "R.id.ondort2" has been used as dublicated

Comment: @pronewby sorry..didnt get you..what was that?